# BindingList & InotifyPropertyChanged

Tags: c#, bindinglist

I have searched all the forum, but I could not find an answer for my question. Maybe I just used the wrong keywords.
Let's assume I have a class Foo:

```
class Foo
{
    string a;
    string b;
}
```

A number of instances of Foo are now saved in a

```
BindingList<Foo> bf;
```

Then I have a second class which realizes some sort of relation between objects of type Foo:

```
class Bar
{
    Foo f1;
    Relation r;
    Foo f2;
}
```

Again, a number of instances of class Bar are saved in a

```
BindingList<Bar> bb;
```

At a certain point in my program, I now delete an instance of Foo, say f7.

```
bb.Remove(f7);
```

Is there any possibility, that exactly those instances of Bar are deleted that hold a reference to f7?
At the moment, I hook on the ListChanged event of bf and manually traverse bb and kill those instances of Bar that contain f7. Is there a smarter way?

Thanks for your help,
Guido

Comment: Did you mean `bf.Remove(f7)`? bb contains Bars, not Foos...

Comment: @ThomasLevesque I think the OP means, he wants to remove from the list if one of the `Foo` properties is equal to `F7`. So it does mean `bb.Remove(f7)` in this case :)

Comment: ops, exactly, i mean bf.Remove(f7)

Comment: Remove does not kill your object. It just removes the reference to the object from your list. If you assign null to the reference first, and then remove the reference, all reference to that object will be null.

Answer (score 1):

Judging by your OP. I suspect that you want something like this. You would have to ensure that your `Foo` objects in `Bar` are the same instance, or implement `IEquatable` on `Foo`.

```
var barWhereFoosExist = bb.Where(x => x.f1.Equals(f7) || x.f2.Equals(f7));
foreach(Bar b in barWhereFoosExist)
{
  bb.Remove(b);
}
```

Try the above using something like this.

```
BindingList<Bar> bb = new BindingList<Bar>();
Foo f7 = new Foo();
Bar b = New Bar();
b.f1 = f7;
b.f2 = new Foo();
```

Comment: @Jan do you mean your already doing this? This is exactly what you are going to do?